# script to copy, delete and symlink

Tags: shell-script, symlink

I want to copy a file to another disk, when completed delete it, and create a symlink back to it in the original location.

example:
copyandlink.sh somefile.iso

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cp $1 /media/storage/linked/ &&
rm $1 &&
ln -s /media/storage/linked/$1 ./
```

or something like that.

Comment: You do know that hard links cannot work across devices, don't you?

Comment: Since the current question is impossible to answer, as pointed out by AlexP, you can either change it to use soft links or similar alternatives, or delete it.

Comment: My mistake, confusing hardlinks and symlinks.

Comment: So what is the question that remains?

Comment: Maybe this is as good as it gets, but it is not very elegant. I thought there would be a better, more robust way.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track since your script does exactly what you want.

It can be simplified and improved a little like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv $1 /media/storage/linked/ &&
ln -s /media/storage/linked/$1 .
```

The `set -e` has no impact since your commands are already conditional with the `&&`.

I also replaced the `cp` and `rm` for `mv` which handles both automatically, whether on the same partition or not.